# Dynamic value append to the dynamic text field using Angular template reference

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following html code, when I click on the button need to be change same row text field value. My question is how to refer the input field and append the value?

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
  <input type="text" #textField{{i}} />
  <button #btn{{i}} (click)="myEvent(i)">Click to Change</button>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  myEvent(i) {
    if(i == 0) {
      // textField0 append a new value to the text field
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks all

[Sample demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydgzgf)

Comment: can you specify  the possible result that you want to achieve  or some sample output. didn't understand the end result or what you are trying to achieve?  Are you trying to get the value into the text field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way by using  [`@ViewChildren()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren):

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
  <input type="text" #textField />  -- Here just use `#textField` without index
   <button #btn{{i}} (click)="myEvent(i)">
    Click to Change
   </button>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
@ViewChildren("textField") textFields: QueryList<ElementRef>;

myEvent(i: any) {
  var feildsArray = this.textFields.toArray();
  feildsArray[i].nativeElement.value = "James";
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akbfjr)

Answer (score 2):

Try without using #template reference variable and just use `[(ngModel)]` instead:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value[i]"/>
    <button #btn{{i}} (click)="myEvent(i,value[i])">Click to Change</button>
</div>

<p *ngFor="let item of data">
    {{item}}
</p>
```

TS:

```
value = [];
data = [];

myEvent(i, value) {
  this.data[i] = value;
}
```

[`Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsyt9l)

Comment: No, but he can use it foe some other purpose like validation or something

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this

```
interface InputModel {
  id: number;
  value: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public inputs: InputModel[] = [
    {id: 1, value: 0},
    {id: 2, value: 0},
    {id: 3, value: 0},
    {id: 4, value: 0},
  ]

  public updateValue(index: number, valueString: string): void {
    this.inputs[index].value = this.inputs[index].value + 1;
  }
}
```

And your template will be

```
<div *ngFor="let item of inputs; let i = index">
  <input type="text" [value]="item.value"/>

  <button (click)="updateValue(i, item.value)">Click to Change</button>
</div>
```